# getting Project with path ':ReactAndroid:hermes-engine' could not be found in project ':ReactAndroid' error with fabric enabled

Tags: react-native, gradle, react-native-reanimated

I am trying to upgrade a react native tvos project to react-native-tvos@0.69.5-2 so that I can enable fabric but am receiving the following error in Android Studio when trying to run the project in emulator:

Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownProjectException: Project with path ':ReactAndroid:hermes-engine' could not be found in project ':ReactAndroid'.

I have the following dependencies installed:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.5",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/devtools": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.2",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "npm:react-native-tvos@0.69.5-2",
    "react-native-android-intent-launcher": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.3.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-mmkv": "^2.4.3",
    "react-native-performance": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-performance-flipper-reporter": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.0.0-rc.3",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.0.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens for me when enabling new arch on android and running gradle clean. Ironically disabling Hermes in all my testing didn't fix the issue.

After reading through the [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34084) and [the official docs on Bundled Hermes](https://reactnative.dev/architecture/bundled-hermes#android-users-on-new-architecture-building-on-windows) I upgraded to RN 71.3, used the [RN upgrade helper to diff my gradle configurations](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.70.6&to=0.71.3)

I removed the following lines from my settings.gradle to resolve the error:

```
if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
    include(":ReactAndroid")
    project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')
}
```

I'd be lying if I said I completely understood why this issue happens, only how I personally fixed it. Hope this can be helpful if anyone else stumbles across this issue.